# unable to insert 03 popup in one page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

i am trying to implement 03 popup on my page but unable to do so. i am trying to achieve this by assigning different ID to each popup. any help is highly appreciated. Here is my code
CSS:

```
.fa {
  font-size: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
}

.fa:hover {
  font-size:20px;
  transition: 1s ease-out;
}

/* Popup container - can be anything you want */
.popup {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

/* The actual popup */
.popup .popuptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 160px;
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 8px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 125%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -80px;
}

/* Popup arrow */
.popup .popuptext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}

/* Toggle this class - hide and show the popup */
.popup .show {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
  animation: fadeIn 1s;
}

/* Add animation (fade in the popup) */
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  from {opacity: 0;} 
  to {opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {opacity: 0;}
  to {opacity:1 ;}
}
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="popup" onclick="myFunction()"><i onclick="myFunctions(this)" class="fau fa fa-plus-circle"></i>
  <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">A Simple Popup!</span>
</div>
```

MY JS Code:

```
// When the user clicks on div, open the popup
function myFunction() {
  var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
  popup.classList.toggle("show");
}
function myFunctions(x) {
  x.classList.toggle("fa-times-circle");
}
```

Here i am trying to apply 2nd popup:

```
<div class="popup" onclick="myFunction()"><i onclick="myFunctions(this)" class="fau fa fa-plus-circle"></i>
  <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup2">A Simple Popup 2</span>
</div>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup2");
  popup.classList.toggle("show");
}
</script>
```

and same for popup three. i am stuck here. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't create more than one function with the same name. However, one solution is create a reusable function and pass the clicked element to it. Then on your popup div also add a data attribute called `data-target` that holds the ID of the popup you want to open.

For example:

`<div class="popup" data-target="myPopup" onclick="myFunction(this)">`

or

`<div class="popup" data-target="myPopup2" onclick="myFunction(this)">`

Then you will only need the below single function, you won't have to duplicate it.

```
function myFunction(el){
  var popup = document.getElementById(el.dataset.target);
  popup.classList.toggle("show");
}
```